# Problem with StdIN/StdOUT pipes when parent process is 64bits

Tags: c#, winapi, pipe, 32bit-64bit

I made a class to start child process that inherit new pipes for standard input/output/error. All is working fine in 32bits: I can write in child StdIn and read child StdOut/Err without problem (the child process can also read the new StdIn pipe and write in the new stdOut/Err pipes).

But, if I compile my parent process in 64bits, the child process (32 and 64bits) cannot read the new pipes.

```
Parent | Child | RedirectPipes | Result (In Child process)
32bits | 32/64 | In+Out        | GOOD
64bits | 32/64 | In+Out        | Access Denied for StdIn (Console.ReadLine)
64bits | 32/64 | In            | *** No error but no data for StdIn.
```

*** When I don't redirect the Output pipe, I can manually write (with my keyboard) in the new window and the child receives that data. So the stdIn isn't redirect.

In all case, no error in parent process

I tried to adjust the SecurityDescriptor of the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES but without success. I know that the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure has a different size in 64bits but I'm not sure if it can be a problem and how to manage that.

Do you have any suggestions? Questions?

Thank you

If you want to test, I made a smaller project with only the minimal.

Parent code :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace Shell.TestShell
{
    class TestShell
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var OneShell = new Shell2();
        }
    }

    class Shell2
    {
        public const Int32 STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x100;
        public const Int32 STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 1;

        public const UInt16 SW_SHOW = 5;
        public const UInt16 SW_HIDE = 0;

        [Flags()]
        public enum CreateProcessFlags
        {
            CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x4,
            DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x8,
            CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x4000000,

            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x10,
            CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x200,
            CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x8000000,
            CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM = 0x800,
            CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x400,
            
            IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40,
            BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x4000,
            ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x8000,
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20,
            HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80,
            REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct StartupInfo
        {
            public int cb;
            public String reserved;
            public String desktop;
            public String title;
            public int x;
            public int y;
            public int xSize;
            public int ySize;
            public int xCountChars;
            public int yCountChars;
            public int fillAttribute;
            public int flags;
            public UInt16 showWindow;
            public UInt16 reserved2;
            public byte reserved3;
            public SafeFileHandle hStdInput;
            public SafeFileHandle hStdOutput;
            public SafeFileHandle hStdError;
        }


        public struct ProcessInformation
        {
            public IntPtr process;
            public IntPtr thread;
            public int processId;
            public int threadId;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName,
                                                string lpCommandLine,
                                                IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
                                                IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
                                                bool bInheritHandles,
                                                CreateProcessFlags dwCreationFlags,
                                                IntPtr lpEnvironment,
                                                string lpCurrentDirectory,
                                                ref StartupInfo lpStartupInfo,
                                                out ProcessInformation lpProcessInformation);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int Length;
            public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
            public bool InheritHandle;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CreatePipe(out SafeFileHandle hReadPipe, out SafeFileHandle hWritePipe, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes, uint nSize);


        public Shell2()
        {
            StartupInfo Shell2StartupInfo = new StartupInfo();
            Shell2StartupInfo.flags       = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
            Shell2StartupInfo.showWindow  = SW_SHOW; // SW_SHOW for testing only
            Shell2StartupInfo.reserved    = null;
            Shell2StartupInfo.cb          = Marshal.SizeOf(Shell2StartupInfo);


            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributesInput = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            lpPipeAttributesInput.InheritHandle       = true;
            lpPipeAttributesInput.Length              = Marshal.SizeOf(lpPipeAttributesInput);
            lpPipeAttributesInput.SecurityDescriptor  = IntPtr.Zero;


            // Parent pipes
            SafeFileHandle StandardInputWriteHandle;
            SafeFileHandle StandardOutputReadHandle;

            // Child pipes
            SafeFileHandle StandardInputReadHandle;
            SafeFileHandle StandardOutputWriteHandle;

            // New pipes for StdIN
            if (!CreatePipe(out StandardInputReadHandle, out StandardInputWriteHandle, ref lpPipeAttributesInput, 0))
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            // New pipes for StdOUT
            if (!CreatePipe(out StandardOutputReadHandle, out StandardOutputWriteHandle, ref lpPipeAttributesInput, 0))
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());


            //  Redirect child pipes
            Shell2StartupInfo.hStdInput  = StandardInputReadHandle;
            Shell2StartupInfo.hStdOutput = StandardOutputWriteHandle;
            //Shell2StartupInfo.hStdOutput = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, false);
            Shell2StartupInfo.hStdError  = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, false);


            String PathProgram;

            // My testing child .Net Application
            //PathProgram = @"C:\Temp\ConsoleEcho32.exe";
            //PathProgram = @"C:\Temp\ConsoleEcho64.exe";

            // cmd.exe same platform (32/64bits) as parent process  
            PathProgram = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";

            // Force 32 bits cmd.exe child from 64bits parent
            //PathProgram = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe";

            // Force 64 bits cmd.exe child from 32bits parent
            //PathProgram = @"C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe";


            FileStream fsOUT = new FileStream(StandardOutputReadHandle, FileAccess.Read, 4096, false);
            StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(fsOUT, Console.OutputEncoding);

            FileStream fsIN = new FileStream(StandardInputWriteHandle, FileAccess.Write, 4096, false);
            StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(fsIN, Console.InputEncoding);

            ProcessInformation ProcessInfo;
            if (!CreateProcess(PathProgram, @"",
                                IntPtr.Zero,
                                IntPtr.Zero,
                                true,
                                CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, // CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE for testing only
                                IntPtr.Zero, @"C:\temp",
                                ref Shell2StartupInfo,
                                out ProcessInfo))
            {
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Child started");
           
            SW.WriteLine("echo Result should be in child process StdOUT");
            //SW.WriteLine(@"echo b > c:\temp\ttt.txt"); // test StdIN without StdOutput
            SW.Flush();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Child output " + i + " : "+ SR.ReadLine());
            }
            
            SW.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("END");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use cmd.exe as child process or, if you prefer, my ConsoleEcho code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleEcho
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
            String PathLog = @"c:\temp\logConsoleEcho.txt";

            try
            {
                File.Delete(PathLog);
                
                File.AppendAllText(PathLog, DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ConsoleEcho begin" + NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ConsoleEcho begin");
                File.AppendAllText(PathLog, "After first WriteLine" + NewLine); // Useful if the process crash of freeze while writing to StdOut

                String Input;
                do
                {
                    Input = Console.ReadLine();
                    File.AppendAllText(PathLog, Input + NewLine);
                    Console.WriteLine(Input);
                } while (Input != null);

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                File.AppendAllText(PathLog, "The last Win32 Error was: " + error + NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine("The last Win32 Error was: " + error);

                File.AppendAllText(PathLog, Ex.ToString() + NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());

                File.AppendAllText(PathLog, Ex.HResult.ToString() + NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.HResult.ToString());

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Using cmd.exe, with a 32bits parent, you should get:**

Parent output

```
Child started
Child output 1 : Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198]
Child output 2 : (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Child output 3 :
Child output 4 : C:\temp>echo Result should be in child process StdOUT
Child output 5 : Result should be in child process StdOUT
END
```

Child Output : Nothing

**Using cmd.exe, with a 64bits parent, you should get:**

Parent output

```
Child started
```

Child Output : Nothing and the cmd.exe will close

**Using ConsoleEcho.exe, with a 32bits parent, you should get:**

Parent output

```
Child started
Child output 1 : 2021-01-22 13:52:24 ConsoleEcho begin
Child output 2 : echo Result should be in child process StdOUT
```

Child Output : Nothing

**Using ConsoleEcho.exe, with a 64bits parent, you should get:**

Parent output

```
Child started
```

Child Output

```
2021-01-22 13:55:15 ConsoleEcho begin
The last Win32 Error was: 5
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__ConsoleStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
   at System.IO.TextReader.SyncTextReader.ReadLine()
   at System.Console.ReadLine()
   at ConsoleEcho.Program.Main(String[] args) in \\..\ConsoleEcho\Program.cs:line 25
-2147024891
```

## .
.
.

Xanatos found the solution.

Here is my approach/mistake if it can help someone :

It was the first time for me with createProcess+CreatePipe and I started with pInvoke definition. But, I had some problem with the redirection of pipes. So, I take a "working" example on Internet (that had this byte/IntPtr definition error). This code was working in 32bits and come with a lot of struct/API definitions. I didn't compared/challenged these definitions against pinvoke.

When I rebuild my project in 64bits, I got the access denied. I searched for hints/solutions and found the "same" error (access denied) with CreateProcess/CreatePipe in 64bits only. According to what I found, their problems was related to the struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES that is different in 32/64bits.

The code I found on Internet also had this bad definition for SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES. But, even after correcting it, the error was still there. I spent several hours trying to fix SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES or anything relate to it.

So, I partially had the answer (wrong definition) but I wasn't looking at the right place. I should have take a step back.

A bad definition (32/64bits) of SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES may result in a access denied with pipe.
But, an access denied with pipe when changing platform (32/64bits) may not be relate to a bad SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES definition...

Comment: `StartupInfo.reserved3` must be an `IntPtr`. It is a LPBYTE here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa The other pinvokes seems to be correct

Comment: I think you got it! Only had one minute to try it on the small project and it worked! Revert the change and it stopped working. Will try with the full project and confirm this after.

Thanks!

Comment: @xanatos I confirm that everything is working fine with a IntPtr type. Thank you. 
I think I can't mark a comment as a answer...?

Comment: This is why one doesn't normally rewrite the API structure definitions for every single project, but uses a working definition such as http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/STARTUPINFO.html

Comment: I agree with you @BenVoigt and I know your comment is a constructive purpose for everyone.

I always start with PInvoke definition but my code wasn't working. So I take a "working" example on Internet (with the byte/IntPtr error) and didn't verified all included definitions. I'm not an expert but I think I would probably found this error (if I wasn't looking at the wrong place and loosing too much time on a small error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartupInfo.reserved3` must be an `IntPtr`. It is a `LPBYTE lpReserved2` in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow).

The other pinvokes seems to be correct